# How to load CSV file in apache spark SCALA

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How to load CSV file
I have two CSV file users and tweets
Where in tweets table I split the record by ','
But In tweet field between two quotes there are so many commas so I'm not getting proper output or primer data

So what is the correct code in Scala?

Comment: could you provide us minimal code example? and what is proper output?

Answer (score 0):

I simply load the file using textfile and then used regex function 
val fields = line.split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)")
and it worked..
Thank You!!

Answer (score -1):

You can read Tweet file with having multiple `,` inside `""` in one field.

```
val data = spark.read.option("header", true).option("delimiter", ",") .option("inferSchema", true).csv("Tweet.csv")
```

Comment: Thank you I've loaded the file but the issue now is the schema . I tried using case class but i'm getting error .can you share me example code of how to load to csv files along with schema using case class as i have to perform joins on it  . without using .option("inferschema" , "true")..thanks in advance

Comment: Create schema as....  val schema1=StructType(Seq(StructField("id",IntegerType,true),StructField("name",StringType,true),StructField("dob",DateType,true)))....then instead of .option("inferschema","true")....use .schema(schema1)......also import org.apache.spark.sql.types._   ... hope this works!!